# Change aphostrohe with AltGr + P using xmodmap

Tags: 13.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, xmodmap

I'm struggling with changing one keybind with `xmodmap`. <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> outputs `þ`, but I would like to change it to output `'`.

`xmodmap -pm` outputs:

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

I can't seem to attach `Alt_R` as one of the modifiers (unless its there as `ISO_Level3_Shift` or `Mode_switch`). Here is what `xev` shows:

```
# - p
KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x2b8, subw 0x0, time 194353, (300,-235), root:(366,280),
    state 0x10, keycode 33 (keysym 0x70, p), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (70) "p"
    XFilterEvent returns: False      


# - altgr
KeyRelease event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x2b8, subw 0x0, time 216040, (249,-329), root:(315,186),
    state 0x90, keycode 108 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

# - altgr+p
KeyPress event, serial 41, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x2b8, subw 0x0, time 230879, (218,-187), root:(284,328),
    state 0x90, keycode 33 (keysym 0xfe, thorn), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c3 be) "þ"
    XmbLookupString gives 2 bytes: (c3 be) "þ"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Whenever I tried to change the binding, it either adds `'` instead of `p` or the cobination doesn't do anything.

**Update:**

Aphostrophe currently shows when I press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd>.

**Update 2:**

`xmodmap -e "keysym THORN = apostrophe"` changes <kbd>P</kbd> to `'` even though xev outputs `THORN` after pressing <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

See the output of `xmodmap -pke` to understand how the "values" of the keys are assigned. For example, by default, if you are using English (UK) keyboard layout, `xmodmap -pke | grep "thorn"` will return:

```
keycode  33 = p P p P section NoSymbol Greek_pi Greek_PI U03E1 U03E0 p P thorn THORN
```

That being said, assuming that you are using English (UK) keyboard layout, use the following command to type apostrophe when you press <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 33 = p P p P section NoSymbol Greek_pi Greek_PI U03E1 U03E0 p P apostrophe quotedbl"
```

To get this change for every session, create a file called `.xmodmap`, with the following command:

```
xmodmap -pke > .xmodmap
```

Then, create a file called `.xinitrc` in your home directory, containing the following line/command:

```
xmodmap .xmodmap
```