# Xmodmap configuration

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I am trying to configure my keyboard to be able to type German characters without trying to learn another completely different keyboard layout. I found the exact stuff that I need to do to Xmodmap:

```
! Map umlauts to RIGHT ALT + <key>
keycode 108 = Mode_switch
keysym e = e E EuroSign
keysym c = c C cent
keysym a = a A adiaeresis Adiaeresis
keysym o = o O odiaeresis Odiaeresis
keysym u = u U udiaeresis Udiaeresis
keysym s = s S ssharp
```

But my problem is, I don't know how to do that. I found some info on how to switch keys, as in page up to where delete is and delete to where page up is, but that isn't what I'm trying to do and my nooby self couldn't figure out how to apply that info to this different situation. I don't even know how to get to Xmodmap  up really. So if anyone knows how to edit Xmodmap to do the things that I need to do to it, I would greatly appreciate it if you would share that info.:)

Comment: Take  look at my answer [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/357012/147044).

Comment: Thanks, but that is all really confusing.:( I'm not a power user.

Answer (score 0):

Make a file called .Xmodmap in your home directory and copy and paste all of that into it. Log out and log back in again, or run `xmodmap ~/.Xmodmap` from the command line.